# cassandra-python driver losing records in select query?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra-2.0

I'm running a bunch of prepared statements against Cassandra 2.0.8 from a python script. I use python-cassandra driver 2.1.4 under python3 installed via pip. The code looks like this:

```
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='xxx',password='xxx')
cluster = Cluster(['xxx'], auth_provider=auth_provider, control_connection_timeout=None)
session = cluster.connect()
session.default_timeout = None
session.set_keyspace(sphere)

select_query = session.prepare("SELECT tag FROM r WHERE r_id=?")

for id in ids:
  res = session.execute(select_query, (int(id),))
  if not res: complain
```

These ids came from Cassandra in the first place, and I checked all the cases when the query returned nothing with cqlsh against the database: they are all there! Can you suggest what can be wrong? This used to work before!

Btw. I have another prepared statement in the same session that is updating this table. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Where are you getting ids? If you have a multi-node cluster and you're doing write-then-read, it's possible your rows are not fully replicated.
Other prepared statements should have no bearing on this.

Comment: Hi Adam! Getting my ids from Cassandra in a different script. I first get the ids and then runs tons of parallel jobs like this, each with its set of ids. I am not using a cluster right now, just a single instance of Cassandra.

Comment: So far I have no reason to suspect that the driver is 'losing records'. What type is contained in 'ids'? Why do you have to cast to int in the parameter list? Have you tried isolating the ids that fail and writing a script to query them with this driver?

Comment: ids are integers in Cassandra, but I'm running the script in parallel via GNU Parallel, so I send in the ids in text and cast them to ints. What I do right now is save all ids for which the query didn't return anything, and rerun the script over them. That works fine. Could it be a configuration problem with Cassandra? Maybe I should switch to the most recent version?

Comment: I have also added `timeout=None` to the call, but same story

Comment: Another detail, this is funny, because I run other scripts in exactly the same fashion, but they run on all records. Maybe the processing time for the record here is too quick and it requests too much and floods Cassandra with too much data to handle...